# Catching an error from byte-compile-file in batch mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, bytecode

I'm trying to write a makefile snippet to compile `.el` files to `.elc` files. I have the following snippet:

```
.el.elc:
        $(EMACS) -q -Q --batch \
                       --eval "(progn
                                 (setq load-path (cons \"$(abs_srcdir)\" load-path)) 
                                 (setq load-path (cons nil load-path))
                                 (defun byte-compile-dest-file (f) \"$@\")
                                 (condition-case nil
                                   (byte-compile-file \"$<\")
                                   (error (kill-emacs 1))))"
```

(I have formatted the snippet for presentation, `make` probably won't like it laid out this way.)

`$(abs_srcdir)` is being defined correctly, but I have two problems:

Firstly: With a directory layout like the following:

```
+- foo.el <- foo.el lives in $(abs_srcdir)
+- _build/
++- bar.el
++- Makefile
```

(That is, a VPATH build where `foo.el` lives in srcdir and I'm trying to build in `_build`.)

If `bar.el` depends on `foo.el` (via `(require 'foo)` and `(provide 'foo)`), attempts to compile `bar.elc` fail with the error:

```
In toplevel form:
../bar.el:1:1:Error: Cannot open load file: foo
```

This strikes me as odd because thought I was consing `$(abs_srcdir)` onto `load-path`. What's happened?

The second problem is that even if this happens, `emacs` is exiting with status 0, despite my efforts to wrap the `(byte-compile-file)` call in a `(condition-case)`. What has happened here?

Comment: `(setq load-path (cons nil load-path))` adds the current directory to `load-path`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html - "A list entry in load-path can also have the special value `nil`, which stands for the current default directory."

Comment: I should also add that for some reason consing nil isn't working for me and I have had to cons `$(abs_builddir)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I had was that with a VPATH build, files in the build directory weren't being found (by calls to `(require)`, for example). For some reason, consing `nil` onto `load-path` doesn't work, but consing `$(abs_srcdir)` works.

The second problem was that I couldn't catch the error raised by `(byte-compile)`. This was solved by [wvxvw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797257/wvxvw): `(byte-compile)` doesn't raise errors, but returns `t` if the compilation succeeds. Therefore, something like:

```
(unless (byte-compile-file "$<") (kill-emacs 1))
```

works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the snippet you gave and did a test case in the directory `~/test`.
I end up with the following three files.

Makefile:

```
abs_srcdir=~/test

all: foo.elc bar.elc

clean:
        rm -rf *.elc

%.elc: %.el
    emacs -Q --batch --eval "(progn (add-to-list 'load-path \"$(abs_srcdir)\") (defun byte-compile-dest-file (f) \"$@\") (condition-case nil (byte-compile-file\"$<\") (error (kill-emacs 1))))"
```

foo.el:

```
(defun foo-fun ()
  (message "foo"))

(provide 'foo)
```

bar.el:
    (require 'foo)

```
(defun bar-fun ()
  (foo-fun))

(provide 'bar)
```

This example works for me and only fails if I give the wrong definition for abs_srcdir.

Comment: Are you working with a VPATH build? I have had no trouble building when all the .el files are in the same directory.

Comment: Even though this doesn't exactly answer my question, have the bounty as a thanks for stopping by.